# Cannot find symbol toArrayList() android react native and react-native-admob

Tags: android, react-native, admob

Deps:

```
"native-base": "2.3.5",
"react": "16.0.0",
"react-native": "0.50.4",
"react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
```

After an update from RN 0.45 to 0.50 and RN-Admob from 1.3.2 to 2.0.0-beta.3

When trying to build with *react-native run-android*

> /node_modules/react-native-admob/android/src/main/java/com/sbugert/rnadmob/RNAdMobInterstitialAdModule.java:117:
>
> error: cannot find symbol
>           ArrayList list = nativeArray.toArrayList();
>
> ```
>                                         ^   symbol:   method toArrayList()   location: variable nativeArray of type
> ```
>
> ReadableNativeArray
>   /Users/dobre/Desktop/projects//node_modules/react-native-admob/android/src/main/java/com/sbugert/rnadmob/RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule.java:129:
>
> error: cannot find symbol
>         ArrayList list = nativeArray.toArrayList();
>
> ```
>                                       ^   symbol:   method toArrayList()   location: variable nativeArray of type
> ```
>
> ReadableNativeArray
>   /Users/dobre/Desktop/projects//node_modules/react-native-admob/android/src/main/java/com/sbugert/rnadmob/RNPublisherBannerViewManager.java:252:
>
> error: cannot find symbol
>           ArrayList list = nativeArray.toArrayList();
>
> ```
>                                         ^   symbol:   method toArrayList()   location: variable nativeArray of type
> ```
>
> ReadableNativeArray
>   /Users/dobre/Desktop/projects//node_modules/react-native-admob/android/src/main/java/com/sbugert/rnadmob/RNPublisherBannerViewManager.java:271:
>
> error: cannot find symbol
>           ArrayList list = nativeArray.toArrayList();
>
> ```
>                                         ^   symbol:   method toArrayList()   location: variable nativeArray of type
> ```
>
> ReadableNativeArray
>   /Users/dobre/Desktop/projects//node_modules/react-native-admob/android/src/main/java/com/sbugert/rnadmob/RNAdMobBannerViewManager.java:223:
>
> error: cannot find symbol
>           ArrayList list = nativeArray.toArrayList();
>
> ```
>                                         ^   symbol:   method toArrayList()   location: variable nativeArray of type
> ```
>
> ReadableNativeArray 5 errors
>   :react-native-admob:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':react-native-admob:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

I tried also RN 0.51 and manual unlink and re-link but nothing worked.

Comment: When using react-native and upgrading packages a lot of times things go broke! Have you tried rm -rf your entire app and reinstalling, then installing, then re linking. This issue sounds like a linking issue, react-native link didn't always work as intended for myself. Ultimately I downgraded to xcode 9 with a manual install then rebuilt through xcode (I don't know xcode well, its easy). This all happened for me when I installed High Sierra and upgraded Xcode. (Hopefully this helps even though you're using android)

Comment: IOS works fine for us ... We have a problem with android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of investigations and unlinking and re-linking I solved it with:

```
  maven {

            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"

        }
```

in `build.gradle` file.

Old url was `"$projectDir/../../node_modules/react-native/android"`

So it was a gradle issue. When building it used to get old react-native android libs.

Answer (score 0):

I think your android project still have the old linking.
You should open your project in android studio and check your main activity class

Comment: I will check it next week and let you know if it works. Thank you!

Comment: I tried to unlink this module and link it again and then i tried to link it manually but nothing work

Comment: try update android build tools in gradle and rebuild your project

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your `MainActivity` first, and even if error occurs. Then i think you have to downgrade your `react-native-admob` version form v2.0.0 to v1.3.2. It will work definitely.

Because, there is some issue in v2.0.0 which is still `beta`. You can check more about this issue on `github` here, https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/issues/231

Comment: Downgrading is not an option for me, I signaled the issue on github. My question is related to v2.0.0 beta and RN>=0.50

Answer (score 0):

**Update the file :- Build.gradle(react-native-admob)**

//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+' // Comment this line

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0' // Add this line